# Fell into infinite loop while receiving file using datainputstream and bufferedinputstream

Tags: java, network-programming, bufferedinputstream, datainputstream

I am trying to build a server program that receives file from client using DataInputStream and BufferedInputStream.

Here's my code and it falls into infinite loop, I think it's because of not using available() but I am not really sure.

```
DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(s.getInputStream()));
//s is socket that connects fine
fos = new FileOutputStream(directory+"/"+filename);

byte b[] = new byte[512]; 
int readByte = din.read(b);
while(readByte != 1){
    fos.write(b);
    readByte = din.read(b);
    //System.out.println("infinite loop...");
}
```

Can anyone tell me why it falls into infinite loop? if it is because of not using available
, would you please tell me how to use it? I actually googled, but I was confused with the usage. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to do `while(readByte != -1)`. See the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D%29) (-1 means there is nothing more to read).

### Response to Comment

This works for me:

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\Rachel\\Desktop\\Test.txt"));
DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(in));
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Rachel\\Desktop\\MyOtherFile.txt");

byte b[] = new byte[512]; 
while(din.read(b) != -1){
    fos.write(b);
}

System.out.println("Got out");
```

Comment: oops.. I see. But even after I changed to  while(readByte != -1) I still fall into infinite loop ....

Comment: I used DataInputStream on top of the BufferedInputStream, not the FileInputStream.. I copied yours except FileInputStream part and I still fall into infinite loop. What I think the problem is that since the server is waiting for the buffer to be filled, it is in finite loop because for the last part of the file, there's no guarantee that byte[512] will be filled. I assume that I need to use available() method.. but not really sure about this

Comment: I fixed the infinite loop! I had to use available() method But thank you Rachel!

Comment: Glad you fixed it. :) It might be a good idea to answer your own question and mark it as the answer in case anyone every runs across the same problem and finds your question.

Answer (score 0):

As Rachel pointed out, the [`read` method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D%29) on DataInputStream returns the number of bytes successfully read in, or -1 if the end has been reached.  The idiomatic way to loop until the end has been reached is `while(readByte != -1)` whereas you had `1` by mistake.  If it is never the case that exactly 1 byte is read then this will be an infinite loop (`readByte` will never change from -1 once the end of the stream has been reached).  If by chance there is an iteration where exactly 1 byte is read, this would have actually terminated early instead of going into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has already been answered but this code has another problem which is corrected below. The canonical stream copy loop looks like this:

```
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
  out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but still falls into infinite loop.. heres what I did   while ((readByte=din.read(b) >0){ fos.write(b, 0, readByte}

Comment: @in His Steps that code cannot possibly loop infinitely unless the input is infinitely long. It will certainly *block* at the end of teh data, if the sender hasn't closed the connection - is that what you mean?

Comment: I used DataInputStream on top of BufferedInputStream and probably the buffer is waiting to be filled.. I assume that causes the infinite loop but not really sure..

Comment: I fixed it! I had to use available() method! Thank you EJP

Comment: @in His Steps more probably you should have used a separate thread to read the socket. available() isn't really much use. Or else a protocol that tells you when you've read the entire current message.